# What is a good faceted search option?

Tags: jquery, search, filter, faceted-search

What is the best out of the box faceted search option. I checked out jgrid but I only need to filter through a list of 200 things with 3 dropdown lists (Category, File Type, Product) so I was looking for something less complex but also has the built in pagination and items per row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DocumentClouds [VisualSearch.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/visualsearch/) is an awesome option if you don't mind the little bit of overhead it has.

It's very customizable and allows you to add your own tags, group tags etc. Check it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Lucene faceted is fast and also scalable in nature.
I find this block interesting for lucene and elasticsearch engine.

http://www.norconex.com/serving-autocomplete-suggestions-fast/

Comment: please provide a full answer, not just a link